# Running Java program without qualifying with package name

Tags: java

Is there a way to run a Java class, which is defined in a package, without giving the package name prefix (by, say, setting the classpath to the appropriate value)?  The only way that I am able to run the class is by prefixing the complete package name to the classname.

Thanks,
Nimmi

Comment: You can set the `main-class` in `META-INF` as well as the `classpath`. You then can just run it with `java -jar myjar.jar`.

Comment: Yes. Bundle the class(es) in a jar, specify it as the main class in the jar manifest, and run java -jar thejar.jar. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html Other than that, no. WHat's the concrete problem in specifying the actual name of the class you want to run? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Wrap it in a shell script or batch file.